# The difference between exec and popen

Tags: php, linux

I want to run an external PHP file on my server I found out that I can use either `exec` or `popen`.

I read that `popen` is used for Windows while, `exec` is used for Linux.

On the other hand I saw examples where `popen` can also be used for Linux. I am still a newbie. Is it possible? Which do you recommend for Linux if both `exec` and `popen` work?

Kindly what are the advantages as I am still confused.

Comment: read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to exec an external app, use `exec()` or `shell_exec()`. `popen()` is used if you need a pointer, which is something similar to what `fopen()` does with files. `fopen()` just opens the pointer to file, nothing else. Then you need other functions (`fread()`, `fwrite()`) to actually work with the file.

The same logic applies to `popen()`.

`exec()` or `shell_exec()` can be used on windows as well as linux.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I am using `popen` to run asynchronous php script from an Apache web app. I was trying `exec`, `shell_exec` and `pclose`(`popen`(...)) and the only one that creates a new process and execute it asynchronously is `popen`. All the others wait for the script to be finish before answering to browser.

My configuration is CentOS7, PHP 5.4.16 and Apache 2.4, haven't tried on Windows.

Comment: In linux - If you use `exec` to run a command with an ampersand (`&`) at the  end - it returns immediately and runs it asynchronously. Question to people: in that case, is there a difference to when using `popen`?

Answer (score 1):

PHP aims to be platform independent. All the process execution functions work on both Linux and Windows (and any other platform supported by PHP). Before you "hear" something from an untrusted source, you are encouraged to read the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php)